# Get selected option values from multiple select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to fetch all selected option values. It works in Firefox but not in Chrome or Safari. Could anyone tell me how we can do same in different way or how I can fix the Chrome/Safari browser issue.

```js
$(".export_option").click(function(e) {
  var payload = $('form').toJSON();
  console.log(payload);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select name="assetType" id="assetType" class="selectclass">
    <option selected disabled>Asset Type (General)</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Internal Only - Win">Internal Only - Win</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Internal Only - Use Case">Internal Only - Use Case</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Peer-to-Peer, Sales Reference Only">Peer-to-Peer/Sales Reference Only</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Public - Customer Press Release">Public - Customer Press Release</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Public - Success Story">Public - Success Story</option>
  </select><br>

  <select name="prodService" id="prodService" class="selectclass">
    <option selected disabled>Product/Service</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="NetBackup">NetBackup</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="NetBackup Appliances">NetBackup Appliances</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="360 Data Management">360 Data Management</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Access">Access</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Access Appliances">Access Appliances</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Application HA">Application HA</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Backup Exec">Backup Exec</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Cloud Catalyst">Cloud Catalyst</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="CloudPoint">CloudPoint</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Data Insight">Data Insight</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="eDiscovery">eDiscovery</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Enterprise Vault">Enterprise Vault</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Enterprise Vault.cloud">Enterprise Vault.cloud</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Flex Appliance">Flex Appliance</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Information Map">Information Map</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="InfoScale">InfoScale</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Resiliency Platform (VRP)">Resiliency Platform (VRP)</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Velocity">Velocity</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Business Critical Services">Business Critical Services</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Consulting Services">Consulting Services</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Education Services">Education Services</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Managed Services">Managed Services</option>
  </select>

  <br>

  <select name="industry" id="industry" class="selectclass">
    <option selected disabled>Industry</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Academic (College & University)">Academic: College/University</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Academic (K-12)">Academic: K-12</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Accountants">Accountants</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Aerospace">Aerospace</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Automotive">Automotive</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Banking & Finance">Banking & Finance</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Chemical Industry">Chemical Industry</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Communication & Media">Communication & Media</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Construction">Construction</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Consulting">Consulting</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Consumer Elec/Hardware">Consumer Elec/Hardware</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Consumer Goods">Consumer Goods</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Energy/Utilities">Energy/Utilities</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Entertainment/Gaming">Entertainment/Gaming</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Food, Drink & Tobacco">Food, Drink & Tobacco</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Government Crime/Justice/Law">Government Crime/Justice/Law</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Government Defense">Government Defense</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Government Federal/Central">Government Federal/Central</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Government Health/Social">Government Health/Social</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Government Public">Government Public</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Government State/Local">Government State/Local</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Healthcare">Healthcare</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Hotel Leisure">Hotel Leisure</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Information Technology">Information Technology</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Insurance">Insurance</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="ISP/ASP/xSP">ISP/ASP/xSP</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Legal Services">Legal Services</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Logistics">Logistics</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Manufacturing">Manufacturing</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Mining & Exploration">Mining & Exploration</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Non Profit /Charity">Non Profit /Charity</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Pharmaceuticals">Pharmaceuticals</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Real Estate">Real Estate</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Retail">Retail</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Software/Online Services">Software/Online Services</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Telecommunications">Telecommunications</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Travel/Hospitality">Travel/Hospitality</option>
  </select>

  <br>

  <select name="geo" id="geo" class="selectclass">
    <option selected disabled>GEO - Region</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="AMS-Public Sector"> AMS-Public Sector </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="AMS-West"> AMS-West </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="AMS - East"> AMS-East </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="AMS-LAMC"> AMS-LAMC </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="AMS-Mid-Market Commercial (Inside sales)"> AMS-Mid-Market Commercial (Inside sales) </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="AMS-Global & Startegic Accounts"> AMS-Global & Startegic Accounts </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="EMEA-North"> EMEA-North </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="EMEA-Central"> EMEA-Central </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="EMEA-South"> EMEA-South </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="EMEA-Emerging"> EMEA-Emerging </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="APJ-Asia South (ASR)"> APJ-Asia South (ASR) </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="APJ-Greater China (GCR)"> APJ-Greater China (GCR) </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="APJ-India (INR)"> APJ-India (INR) </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="APJ-Japan (JPR)"> APJ-Japan (JPR) </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="APJ-Kora (KOR)"> APJ-Kora (KOR) </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="APJ-Pacific (PAR)"> APJ-Pacific (PAR) </option>
  </select>

  <br>

  <select name="competitor" id="competitor" class="selectclass">
    <option selected disabled>Competitor</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Cohesity">Cohesity</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Commvault">Commvault</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Dell EMC">Dell/EMC</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="HPE">HPE</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="IBM">IBM</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Microsoft">Microsoft</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Rubrik">Rubrik</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Veeam">Veeam</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Zerto">Zerto</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>

  <br>

  <select name="usecase" id="usecase" class="selectclass">
    <option selected disabled>Use Case</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Cloud Service Provider">Cloud Service Provider</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Multi-Cloud Data Management">Multi-Cloud Data Management</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Backup & Recovery">Backup & Recovery</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Business Continuity">Business Continuity</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Software Defined Storage">Software Defined Storage</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Information Governance">Information Governance</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: `toJSON()` isn't a standard jQuery method, so you may be missing a library reference. Also, `click` event handlers on `option` elements are very flaky and, generally speaking, a bad idea. Use a `change` event on the `select` instead.

Comment: Can you try changing to 
`$(".selectclass").on('change',function(e) {
  var payload = JSON.stringify($('form'));
  console.log(payload);});`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily loop over the form elements to populate a map. If the form contains a multi-select drop-down, the `jQuery.fn.val` function will take care of grabbing all the values. Note: I made the last drop-down a multi-select.

```js
// Simple form elements to JSON function.
function formToJSON(form) {
  return [].reduce.call(form.elements, (result, el) => {
    return Object.assign(result, { [el.name]: $(el).val() });
  }, {});
}

// jQuery plugin wrapper.
(function($) {
  $.fn.formToJSON = function() {
    return formToJSON(this[0]);
  };
})(jQuery);

$('form').change('.export_option', function(e) {
  let payload = $('form').formToJSON();
  console.log(payload);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { bottom: 0; max-height: 25% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select name="assetType" id="assetType" class="selectclass">
    <option selected disabled>Asset Type (General)</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Internal Only - Win">Internal Only - Win</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Internal Only - Use Case">Internal Only - Use Case</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Peer-to-Peer, Sales Reference Only">Peer-to-Peer/Sales Reference Only</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Public - Customer Press Release">Public - Customer Press Release</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Public - Success Story">Public - Success Story</option>
  </select><br>

  <select name="prodService" id="prodService" class="selectclass">
    <option selected disabled>Product/Service</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="NetBackup">NetBackup</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="NetBackup Appliances">NetBackup Appliances</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="360 Data Management">360 Data Management</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Access">Access</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Access Appliances">Access Appliances</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Application HA">Application HA</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Backup Exec">Backup Exec</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Cloud Catalyst">Cloud Catalyst</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="CloudPoint">CloudPoint</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Data Insight">Data Insight</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="eDiscovery">eDiscovery</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Enterprise Vault">Enterprise Vault</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Enterprise Vault.cloud">Enterprise Vault.cloud</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Flex Appliance">Flex Appliance</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Information Map">Information Map</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="InfoScale">InfoScale</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Resiliency Platform (VRP)">Resiliency Platform (VRP)</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Velocity">Velocity</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Business Critical Services">Business Critical Services</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Consulting Services">Consulting Services</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Education Services">Education Services</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Managed Services">Managed Services</option>
  </select>

  <br>

  <select name="industry" id="industry" class="selectclass">
    <option selected disabled>Industry</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Academic (College & University)">Academic: College/University</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Academic (K-12)">Academic: K-12</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Accountants">Accountants</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Aerospace">Aerospace</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Automotive">Automotive</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Banking & Finance">Banking & Finance</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Chemical Industry">Chemical Industry</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Communication & Media">Communication & Media</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Construction">Construction</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Consulting">Consulting</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Consumer Elec/Hardware">Consumer Elec/Hardware</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Consumer Goods">Consumer Goods</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Energy/Utilities">Energy/Utilities</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Entertainment/Gaming">Entertainment/Gaming</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Food, Drink & Tobacco">Food, Drink & Tobacco</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Government Crime/Justice/Law">Government Crime/Justice/Law</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Government Defense">Government Defense</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Government Federal/Central">Government Federal/Central</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Government Health/Social">Government Health/Social</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Government Public">Government Public</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Government State/Local">Government State/Local</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Healthcare">Healthcare</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Hotel Leisure">Hotel Leisure</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Information Technology">Information Technology</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Insurance">Insurance</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="ISP/ASP/xSP">ISP/ASP/xSP</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Legal Services">Legal Services</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Logistics">Logistics</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Manufacturing">Manufacturing</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Mining & Exploration">Mining & Exploration</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Non Profit /Charity">Non Profit /Charity</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Pharmaceuticals">Pharmaceuticals</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Real Estate">Real Estate</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Retail">Retail</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Software/Online Services">Software/Online Services</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Telecommunications">Telecommunications</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Travel/Hospitality">Travel/Hospitality</option>
  </select>

  <br>

  <select name="geo" id="geo" class="selectclass">
    <option selected disabled>GEO - Region</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="AMS-Public Sector"> AMS-Public Sector </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="AMS-West"> AMS-West </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="AMS - East"> AMS-East </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="AMS-LAMC"> AMS-LAMC </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="AMS-Mid-Market Commercial (Inside sales)"> AMS-Mid-Market Commercial (Inside sales) </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="AMS-Global & Startegic Accounts"> AMS-Global & Startegic Accounts </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="EMEA-North"> EMEA-North </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="EMEA-Central"> EMEA-Central </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="EMEA-South"> EMEA-South </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="EMEA-Emerging"> EMEA-Emerging </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="APJ-Asia South (ASR)"> APJ-Asia South (ASR) </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="APJ-Greater China (GCR)"> APJ-Greater China (GCR) </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="APJ-India (INR)"> APJ-India (INR) </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="APJ-Japan (JPR)"> APJ-Japan (JPR) </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="APJ-Kora (KOR)"> APJ-Kora (KOR) </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="APJ-Pacific (PAR)"> APJ-Pacific (PAR) </option>
  </select>

  <br>

  <select name="competitor" id="competitor" class="selectclass">
    <option selected disabled>Competitor</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Cohesity">Cohesity</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Commvault">Commvault</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Dell EMC">Dell/EMC</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="HPE">HPE</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="IBM">IBM</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Microsoft">Microsoft</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Rubrik">Rubrik</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Veeam">Veeam</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Zerto">Zerto</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>

  <br>

  <select name="usecase" id="usecase" class="selectclass" multiple>
    <option selected disabled>Use Case</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Cloud Service Provider">Cloud Service Provider</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Multi-Cloud Data Management">Multi-Cloud Data Management</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Backup & Recovery">Backup & Recovery</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Business Continuity">Business Continuity</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Software Defined Storage">Software Defined Storage</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Information Governance">Information Governance</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following demo delegates [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event to `form` then on [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) `select` it's [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is saved in a variable.

### Demo

```js
$("form").on('change', function(e) {
  console.clear();
  $('select').each(function() {
    var payload = $(this).val();
    console.log(payload);
  });
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 45%;
  margin-left:55%;
}
.as-console-row.as-console-row::after {
  content:'';
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0;
  width:0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="assetType" id="assetType" class="selectclass">
    <option selected disabled>Asset Type (General)</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Internal Only - Win">Internal Only - Win</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Internal Only - Use Case">Internal Only - Use Case</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Peer-to-Peer, Sales Reference Only">Peer-to-Peer/Sales Reference Only</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Public - Customer Press Release">Public - Customer Press Release</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Public - Success Story">Public - Success Story</option>
  </select><br>

  <select name="prodService" id="prodService" class="selectclass">
    <option selected disabled>Product/Service</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="NetBackup">NetBackup</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="NetBackup Appliances">NetBackup Appliances</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="360 Data Management">360 Data Management</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Access">Access</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Access Appliances">Access Appliances</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Application HA">Application HA</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Backup Exec">Backup Exec</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Cloud Catalyst">Cloud Catalyst</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="CloudPoint">CloudPoint</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Data Insight">Data Insight</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="eDiscovery">eDiscovery</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Enterprise Vault">Enterprise Vault</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Enterprise Vault.cloud">Enterprise Vault.cloud</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Flex Appliance">Flex Appliance</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Information Map">Information Map</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="InfoScale">InfoScale</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Resiliency Platform (VRP)">Resiliency Platform (VRP)</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Velocity">Velocity</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Business Critical Services">Business Critical Services</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Consulting Services">Consulting Services</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Education Services">Education Services</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Managed Services">Managed Services</option>
  </select>

  <br>

  <select name="industry" id="industry" class="selectclass">
    <option selected disabled>Industry</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Academic (College & University)">Academic: College/University</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Academic (K-12)">Academic: K-12</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Accountants">Accountants</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Aerospace">Aerospace</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Automotive">Automotive</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Banking & Finance">Banking & Finance</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Chemical Industry">Chemical Industry</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Communication & Media">Communication & Media</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Construction">Construction</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Consulting">Consulting</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Consumer Elec/Hardware">Consumer Elec/Hardware</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Consumer Goods">Consumer Goods</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Energy/Utilities">Energy/Utilities</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Entertainment/Gaming">Entertainment/Gaming</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Food, Drink & Tobacco">Food, Drink & Tobacco</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Government Crime/Justice/Law">Government Crime/Justice/Law</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Government Defense">Government Defense</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Government Federal/Central">Government Federal/Central</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Government Health/Social">Government Health/Social</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Government Public">Government Public</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Government State/Local">Government State/Local</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Healthcare">Healthcare</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Hotel Leisure">Hotel Leisure</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Information Technology">Information Technology</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Insurance">Insurance</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="ISP/ASP/xSP">ISP/ASP/xSP</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Legal Services">Legal Services</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Logistics">Logistics</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Manufacturing">Manufacturing</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Mining & Exploration">Mining & Exploration</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Non Profit /Charity">Non Profit /Charity</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Pharmaceuticals">Pharmaceuticals</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Real Estate">Real Estate</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Retail">Retail</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Software/Online Services">Software/Online Services</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Telecommunications">Telecommunications</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Travel/Hospitality">Travel/Hospitality</option>
  </select>

  <br>

  <select name="geo" id="geo" class="selectclass">
    <option selected disabled>GEO - Region</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="AMS-Public Sector"> AMS-Public Sector </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="AMS-West"> AMS-West </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="AMS - East"> AMS-East </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="AMS-LAMC"> AMS-LAMC </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="AMS-Mid-Market Commercial (Inside sales)"> AMS-Mid-Market Commercial (Inside sales) </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="AMS-Global & Startegic Accounts"> AMS-Global & Startegic Accounts </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="EMEA-North"> EMEA-North </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="EMEA-Central"> EMEA-Central </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="EMEA-South"> EMEA-South </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="EMEA-Emerging"> EMEA-Emerging </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="APJ-Asia South (ASR)"> APJ-Asia South (ASR) </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="APJ-Greater China (GCR)"> APJ-Greater China (GCR) </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="APJ-India (INR)"> APJ-India (INR) </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="APJ-Japan (JPR)"> APJ-Japan (JPR) </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="APJ-Kora (KOR)"> APJ-Kora (KOR) </option>
    <option class="export_option" value="APJ-Pacific (PAR)"> APJ-Pacific (PAR) </option>
  </select>

  <br>

  <select name="competitor" id="competitor" class="selectclass">
    <option selected disabled>Competitor</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Cohesity">Cohesity</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Commvault">Commvault</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Dell EMC">Dell/EMC</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="HPE">HPE</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="IBM">IBM</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Microsoft">Microsoft</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Rubrik">Rubrik</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Veeam">Veeam</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Zerto">Zerto</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>

  <br>

  <select name="usecase" id="usecase" class="selectclass">
    <option selected disabled>Use Case</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Cloud Service Provider">Cloud Service Provider</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Multi-Cloud Data Management">Multi-Cloud Data Management</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Backup & Recovery">Backup & Recovery</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Business Continuity">Business Continuity</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Software Defined Storage">Software Defined Storage</option>
    <option class="export_option" value="Information Governance">Information Governance</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```